# IMAP Support for Vala Programming Language

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, imap, vala

I am planning to write a Mail Client for Ubuntu 14.04. I have used other mail clients and (no offense, but) they all seem to be lacking in one area or another. E.g. Interface, Features (or buggy features) - even simple features like attaching files seem to be lacking in some of them.

The other day I finished a simple mail client for Windows using the AE.NET.Mail IMAP library in C#. But I am having some difficulty trying to figure out how to implement a mail client in Vala for Ubuntu.

I am looking at the Vala documentation right now, and I do not see any IMAP or SMTP stuff anywhere. Are there any IMAP libraries available for the Vala programming language? How do we implement IMAP support in Vala?

Comment: AE.Net.Mail is not a good choice for writing an IMAP client - it loses untagged responses: https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail/issues/154 - a better library to use would be [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). FWIW, Geary uses my MIME parser :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an IMAP client library written in C (not C++) and [create a binding](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Bindings)—I found a bunch of them by searching for "imap c library".  Or you can copy the code from [Geary](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary), which is an e-mail client written in Vala.

That said, there are a large number of open source e-mail clients already.  Instead of writing a new one from scratch because of something you don't like, why not try to fix it?  I'm sure the developers behind Geary, [Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution), [Claws](http://www.claws-mail.org/), [Balsa](http://pawsa.fedorapeople.org/balsa/), [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/), [KMail](https://userbase.kde.org/KMail), [Mailpile](https://www.mailpile.is/), or pretty much [any other mail client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients) would love to have some more help.

Comment: Sorry about that. I decided to try compiling it from source again after many failed attempts months ago. I finally have been able to compile it from source - now I just need to pick an IDE to work with! Thanks for your help. My original intention was to help out with Geary, months ago but I was just unable to get it to build. But, it's working now.